How can i check whether there is any cloud job is running or not in c#
How can I check whether there is any cloud job is running or not in c#?
Becuase want to trigger next only when there is no any in progress job.
I want documentation regarding this question.
I go though following link
https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Infrastructure-Compute-Storage/Cloud-run-job-trigger-when-another-job-completes/td-p/618444
but didn't got any findings.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I don't have any code, I am just triggering cloud job from cloud run service in c# but now I want to check is there any previously running job or not because I want to run only one job at a time.
